# Is it advisable to prefix function name with get without a setter function

Tags: oop

This is a sample code. A class `Foo` that has a `getBar` function without `setBar` function

```
class Foo {
    ...
    public function getBar() {
        return 'Bar';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with that.

Just because a class provides read access to a member, there is no reason why it has to provide write access, and this is often undesirable.